# Can an infinitive phrase itself be used as a proper sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, infinitives

I found 1a on a Jr. High EFL listening test. Is the punctuation here in 1a acceptable in this context?

> 1a) There are many things I have to do on Saturday. **To clean my room and to water my garden.**

I agree that there are better ways that 1a could be written. But my question is, is it acceptable to treat an infinitive phrase as a complete sentence like this?

Please answer with a reputable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that is incorrect, especially if it's on an EFL test.  A complete sentence must have a subject and verb.  Your second clause is a [sentence fragment](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/620/1/) that probably should be joined with the first sentence.  I'd suggest, "There are many things I have to do on Saturday, like clean my room and water my garden."

Comment: I would say *like clean**ing** my room and water**ing** my garden.*

Comment: I would personally just exchange the period with a semicolon . But it's not that easy. I have to be able to show proof that this is wrong. I believe it is wrong. I need to see the linguistic rule from a reputable source that says this is wrong. Otherwise it is just an opinion and I cannot influence the teacher I'm in contest with.

Comment: Thank you. I just looked at the link that you provided. I think it will be enough. Who is the authority on what is an incorrect sentence anyway? I've seen the craziest shenanigans being passed for acceptable.